# You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.

Tags: reactjs, npm, babeljs

**I just made a package with npm publish and install back to fresh project but its giving the above this error**

```
> ./node_modules/react-js-validator/src/inputs/EmailInput.js
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (38:12)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
|     render() {
|         return (
|             <div >
|                 <span className="error-span" style={this.props.styleError} >
|                     {this.state.errorStatus ? this.state.errorMsg : null}
```

from line no 38 my html **div** is starting.

my package.json of npm package is here

```
{    
          "name": "react-js-validator",
          "version": "1.0.9",
          "description": "a simple package for apply input validation on react js validation such as numaric,email,letter,custom rejex,minimum length and max length etc",
          "main": "index.js",
          "scripts": {
            "start": "react-scripts start",
            "build": "react-scripts build",
            "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
            "eject": "react-scripts eject"
          },

          "author": "anil sidhu",
          "license": "ISC",
          "devDependencies": {
            "autoprefixer": "7.1.2",
            "babel": "^6.23.0",
            "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
            "babel-core": "6.25.0",
            "babel-eslint": "7.2.3",
            "babel-jest": "20.0.3",
            "babel-loader": "^7.1.1",
            "babel-plugin-transform-es2015-destructuring": "^6.23.0",
            "babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread": "^6.26.0",
            "babel-preset-react-app": "^3.0.3",
            "babel-runtime": "6.26.0"
          },
          "transpile": "babel src/index.js --out-file src/index-transpiled.js"
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just got the answer we can not use pure html code in npm package for react. use code like this

```
render() {

    let collection = React.createElement("div", {},
        React.createElement("span", { className: 'error-span' }, this.state.errorMsg),
        React.createElement("input", {
            type: "text",
            onChange: (e) => this.Valid(e.target.value),
            onClick: (e) => this.props.return(this.state.errorStatus)
        }
        )
    )
    return (collection)
}
```